# Tensor product, coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors

Find the coordinates of bivector u⊗v with the respect to cannonical basis and basis M = ((1,2),(1,3)), u = (1,1) v=(1,-2). Please help, does it even have the solution? After the tensor multiplication the matrix is singlular?

Answer (score 1):

$$ u=\{\text{u1},\text{u2}\}, v=\{\text{v1},\text{v2}\} $$
$$ \text{uv}=u\otimes v=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \text{u1} \text{v1} & \text{u1} \text{v2} \\
 \text{u2} \text{v1} & \text{u2} \text{v2} \\
\end{array}
\right) $$
$$ \left| \text{uv}\right|=0 $$

The determinant of the matrix that represents the tensor product of any 2 vectors will always be singular.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, i have already figured it out. :) I found the transformation.